# Ubuntu 11.10 gives black screen on boot

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've been having a problem with Ubuntu 11.10. I've tried installing it using Wubi, a USB stick, and a traditional install CD, but no matter what method I use, as soon as the GRUB screen disappears my screen goes blank. The backlight even turns off.

I'm on a Dell  Vostro desktop, using NVIDIA Optimus graphics (it's a prototype). Most of the answers I've found elsewhere suggest installing drivers, but I can't do that because the system never boots.

This is a constant issue, by the way.  I have yet to get even as far as the login screen. I know that my install image isn't corrupted, as I tested it on my laptop and it worked perfectly. Any help anyone can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: If there are specific drivers that have been suggested to you to install, you probably can install them. It should at least be possible to make your system boot nongraphically. Even if not, you may be able to boot from a live CD, `chroot` into your system, and install drivers. Can you edit your question to provide details about drivers that people have suggested for you to install (including but not limited to links to where they have suggested it, if such is available)? Also, as a separate thing to try, have you tried [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)?